# Scroll Image View to Top Programmatically

Tags: android, image, scroll, imageview

I am using TouchImageView in my app to display images.
https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView

As far as I know, Android does not have an easy way to show an image Top Cropped. The best I can do is to Center Crop the Image, which causes the top and bottom of the image to extend off of the screen.

Is there a way to programmatically scroll my image after it has been loaded, and then call ImageView.setVisibility(true)?

I've tried image.scrollBy(int x, int y); 
but I'm not sure exactly how to use it.

I do have the ability to get pixel values for both my screen, and for my image before it is scaled, but don't know what function I should use those values in.

Thanks for your input.